# Swift DiacriticInsensitiveSearch for ø

Tags: nsstring, swift2

When implementing a `searchBar`, I wanted the `searchBar` to ignore accents and case, so I used the following line of code:

```
let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: [NSStringCompareOptions.DiacriticInsensitiveSearch, NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch])
```

However, this does not seem to find the following string when searching for `BLOF`

```
BLØF & Nielson - Mannenharten (officiële video)
```

Is there any way to improve the `searchBar` to see a ø as a o, just like it does with the other accents already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Wikipedia article about Ø. Quote:

> ... Although these names suggest it is a ligature or a diacritical
>   variant of the letter o, it is considered a separate letter in
>   Norwegian and Danish ...

It means that you can't strip accents to get `O`, because it's not accented character. Simply `Ø != O + accent`.

You can think that you can convert it to`O` manually. It's not good idea IMHO, because `Ø` is frequently replaced by `OE` in characters sets not supporting `Ø`. Frequently doesn't mean always.

Just leave it as it is, compare against `Ø`. It's not `O`, it's not `O` without accent, it's not ligature, it's a separate character in Norwegian and Swedish languages.